# AngularJS ng-class condition

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following HTML element with AngularJS directives:

```
<div class="progress">                                                   
 <span ng-repeat="timeRangeObject in timeRangeObjects" style="width: {{timeRangeObject.percentage}}%" ng-class="vm.showVacation == true ? 'progress-bar timerange-{{timeRangeObject.containerType}}' : 'progress-bar timerange-PADDING'" />                                                                             
</div>
```

So I concat more than one progress bar with different types/colors.
With the checkbox I will set specific progress bars to color transparent.

Therefore I would need something like this:

```
... ng-class="vm.showVacation == true ? 'progress-bar timerange-{{timeRangeObject.containerType}}' : 'progress-bar timerange-PADDING | timeRangeObject.containerType == 'XY''"
```

-> so I would need a filter concerning the ng-class else statement.

Is this possible? The important thing is that only color should change but progress bar should stay where it is.

Thanks a lot

[EDIT]
Here is a link to my problem: 
[My Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zz5z6dor/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a done a lot of thing that is better if you correct first of all don't use `style="width:{{}}"` is better if you use ng-style so you don't have to use the bracket, and to answer to your question you can write like this in your ng-class:

```
<div ng-class="foo()">
```

js

```
$scope.foo=function(){
   return /*here you put your condition sorry but i didn't understand
            the conditions you need*/
}
```

you can do this with your style attribute too.

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't know if it is possible to handle the condition. The condition is - if checkbox is clicked than all progress bars should be transparency except those one where the property containerType of the JavaScript - objects has the value 'VACATION'. Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is, you can put ng-model in your checkbox and pass the variable in foo() if yoy do a fiddle i'll let you see

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot!! Here is my problem: [My example](https://jsfiddle.net/zz5z6dor/1/), If I click the checkbox thanI only will show vacation. (Sorry but I could not separate script and html - it didn't work - I dont know why)